# RPM not getting installed while logging using expect script

Tags: expect, rpm

I am trying to install a rpm package after logging into a virtual machine(VM) using expect script.
The logging is fine but when trying to run rpm command it is exiting from the VM and returning back to the called machine.
The command called for rpm installation
rpm -ivh --force pkg_name

To login using expect I use 
spawn ssh root@1.1.1.1 and then when it expects the password I send it.

Has anybody faced such problems?
Any help will be useful.
Thanks.

Below is the expect file to login to the system 
login_script.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 60
set prompt {[#>$] }

system "rm -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts" 
spawn ssh root@1.1.1.1

expect {
    "yes/no" {
         send "yes\r"
         expect {
              "*?assword: " {
                   send "abcdefgh\r" 
                   expect -re $prompt {}
                   }
                }
             }
    "*?assword" { 
         send "abcdefgh\r"
         expect -re $prompt {}
             }
    }
send "sleep 1\r"
send "sudo -i\r"
expect "*?assword" { send "abcdefgh\r" }
```

And the original script will call

```
/usr/bin/expect << -EOF-
source login_script.exp

expect "\$prompt"    ;# wait for prompt
send "rpm -ivh --force /tmp/pkg_abc\r"
expect "\$prompt"    ;# wait for prompt
-EOF-
```

Output for both:

[root@

```
YYY-BServer01 ~]# rpm -ivvh --force /tmp/pkg_abc
D: ============== /tmp/pkg_abc
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:0x401
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages 0x400 mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#
```

622 Header sanity check: OK-bash-4.1#

Comment: Include your expect script. Also using `--force` is almost **always** a bad idea.

Comment: Added the script.
The rpm is starting to get installed but it is stopping after the first line
Preparing    100%
After then it stops and logs out

Comment: That "original script" works? Or do you mean that `login_script.exp` works by itself and you are having trouble with the "original script"? Because that "original script" looks rather wrong to me.

Comment: You probably just need to tell expect not to timeout/exit and wait for longer instead.

Comment: I tried that adding timeout to the script.Other calls are working like ls,echo,cp etc..only rpm is giving problems

Comment: How long are you telling expect to wait? How long does installing that package take? Is expect dying at exactly the timeout length?

Comment: i am waiting for 600 sec. rpm is coming out within fraction of sec

Comment: Try `-ivvh` and `-Uvvh` and include the output you get in the post.

Comment: [root@YYY-BServer01 ~]# rpm -ivvh --force /tmp/pkg_abc
D: ============== /tmp/pkg_abc
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:0x401
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages 0x400 mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#     622 Header sanity check: OK-bash-4.1#

This is with rpm -ivvh
By the way the rpm works normally and with python.

Comment: -Uvvh also has the same output.
It would have continued from there and the next line would have been the below but it stopped there.

D: added key gpg-pubkey-c105b9de-4e0fd3a3 to keyring
D:  read h#     745 Header sanity check: OK
D: added key gpg-pubkey-6b8d79e6-3f49313d to keyring
D:  read h#     746 Header sanity check: OK

Comment: Put the output in the question so you can format it.

Comment: The problem was happening because of having -h in the rpm command..After I removed the -h from rpm parameter the command worked.Thanks Etan for your help. :)

Comment: Hah! `-h` was spitting out `#` characters and I bet that was triggering your expect blocks on `$prompt`. If you can confirm that I would say you should post it as an answer and accept it.